# Can cellphone packets be read by someone who only has your phone number?

Tags: network, smartphone, spyware

I got an IM from a person I recently got acquainted with this year. In the text message, he asked me if I knew the name of the website you download free ebooks from (libgen.is) I found it really weird he asked me this the same day I went on this website through my phone for the first time. And besides, there are only two weeks before we end school. I asked him for proof showing his professor urgently needed students to buy the book now, even with all that's happening. He didn't provide me with much.  I'm wondering, what are the odds this was only a coincidence? I have a feeling he knows someone who has some stealth spyware installed in my phone. I'm only this paranoid because someone else had recently came through confessing they had gone through my phone to check its IMEI. I got a new phone now, but with the same number, and broke ties with that person. Is it entirely possible someone could have access to my browsing history or geolocation just by them having my phone number?

Answer (score 0):

Simply no, unless "someone" is your phone provider. But, knowing your phone number allows them to communicate with you, potentially social engineering their way into getting access.

> I'm only this paranoid because someone else had recently came through
>   confessing they had gone through my phone to check its IMEI.

I'm not entirely sure what this means, but if somebody else had physical access to your device, then it's not your device anymore. Anything is fair game at that point.